# How to remove black overlay on status bar on android with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, statusbar

I'm learning React Native (without React knowledge), but my problem is the status bar always get a translucent black background and I can remove it. I tried every stackoverflow answer, and even React Native and Expo documentation. But nothing...

Here is my problem:
[image]

The status bar has a white background supposedly, and get this grey overlay, that is what I want to remove.

Here is my code:

```js
render() {
    return (
         <View>
             <StatusBar background="white" />
             <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this._signInAsync} />
         </View>
    );
}
```

I even tried this, on app.js

```
"androidStatusBar": {
    "backgroundColor": "#C2185B"
},
```

I'm starting to think, this is related to Expo.

Comment: On two of my older Android devices the StatusBar backgroudColor works. On my OP 6T it just displays grey bar. iPhoneXR on simulator is transparent it seems no matter what I do. I'm struggling to find an acceptable setting that works for all devices even if I reluctantly accept the grey bar on my modern Android. The best I have come up with is setting backgroundColor to white (my app has white background) and icons to dark. Looks bad on the grey bar Android OP 6T as it's black icons on grey bar but I'll have to live with it for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to have white status bar then use below code:

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar backgroundColor='white' barStyle="dark-content" />
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to Pradnya's</Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

}

in the above code "backgroundColor" will change status bar color to white and barStyle="dark-content" will set text color to black as below output:

[image]

and if you want to set background color to suppose "red" then change barstyle="light-content" that will show below output:

[image]

This should solve your issue..

Comment: I tried this and other suggestions, but it is still not working. Could it be because of Expo or react-navigation?

Comment: documentation says "Expo makes the status bar translucent by default on Android which is consistent with iOS, and more in line with material design. Unfortunately some libraries don't support translucent status bar, e.g. - navigation libraries, libraries which provide a header bar etc."  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-statusbar/  It seems you have tried this but if not this link will provide you some info.

Comment: My conclusion, is that nothing can be done because of the plugins I use, specifically the combination between react-navigation and expo.

Comment: Did anyone get any further on this? In theory there should be no conflict between react navigation and status bar but I am seeing the exact problems here. I can set a blank view with backgorund colour but it gets a "mix" colour of the android grey plus my colour.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with the hidden function of StatusBar.

```js
<View>
  <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content" />
  <View>
    <StatusBar hidden={route.statusBarHidden} />
    ...
  </View>
</View>
```

See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html) for more information.

Please leave a comment for further comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this hides my status bar. I want it to be visible, but without that black-transparent background

Comment: You can use `translucent` prop in status bar which will help you to draw your app under status bar, so that you can set your own colour by giving a view with height `20` then you can customise the colour as per your requirement.